# Minimizable side panel in html

Tags: javascript, html, panel

I'm looking for a simple javascript to create side panel with hiding after some action(ex. after clicking on some area). Something like [this example](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/javascript-and-css-tutorial-how-to-make-sliding-panels) but appearing from left side not from up to down as the example works.
Will be appreciated for any help :)

Comment: why dont you use jQuery.Its a simple task with jQuery

Comment: I think it's the most popular solution, but I wanted to find some alternatives to chose the best one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options. You can either use JQuery or scriptaculous to do this. There are plenty of examples and tutorials on the internet or you can simply use java script to this.
First download [émile](https://github.com/madrobby/emile) It's a very simple javascript animation framework.

Since you didn't provide any HTML markup, I'm assuming you have something like this.

```
<div id="side-panel">panel content..</div>
<div id="content">main content..</div>
```

and let's say your side-panel element has a CSS style of `width:200px`. Ok, now place a button somewhere and assign it a click event. Such as `onclick="togglePanel()"`

Here is the content of the togglePanel function:

```
function togglePanel(){
    var panel = document.getElementById('side-panel');
    if(!panel.__closed){
        emile(panel, 'width:0px');
        panel.__closed = true;
    }else{
        emile(panel, 'width:200px');
        panel.__closed = false;
    }
}
```

If you check the documentation of the emile framework you can do lot's of other cool things.

Comment: There are way more then two options, even if you limit answers to "Use a library".

Comment: Why don't you do it with Jquery, it lot more easier.

Comment: I just don't like adding a complete library for just a simple action. emile is only 50 lines of code and can do all types of animations. JQuery seems to be overkill here. Besides he can convert this script to jQuery very easily.

Answer (score 0):

as you haven't provided us your code (which you have build) that's why I'm just giving a code to help you (And I don't know that this is a right answer or not). This code needs `jQuery Ver.1.4` at least I think so, but I'm not clear. Anyways let's get started. Here is a link to [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/divinemamgai/CzATU/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, this example looks as one I was looking for :)

Comment: Hey Nozim, if Jack Billy's answer is perfect then why don't you accept his answer.